# Directives not working in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, angular2-directives

Directive example in ionic 3, method used previously are not working.
Already tried the way in which directives where implemented in ionic 2.

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
   selector: 'test',
   template: './test.html'
)}
export class MyDirective { }

import {MyDirective } from './test'

@Page({
   templateUrl: '../page.html',
   directives: [MyDirective ],
})
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can see what is happening.

Comment: added @WesleyCoetzee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following:

ComponentA, parent component

**acomponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-a',
    templateUrl: 'acomponent.html'
})
export class ComponentA { }
```

**acomponent.html**

```
<div>
  <h3>Component A</h3>
  <component-b></component-b>
</div>
```

**bcomponent.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-b',
    templateUrl: 'bcomponent.html'
})
export class ComponentB { }
```

**bcomponent.html**

```
<h3>Component B</h3>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ComponentA } from 'pathto/acomponent';
import { ComponentB } from 'pathto/bcomponent';
//other imports here too

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
    //other declarations
  ],
  imports: [//your imports],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
    //other entryComponents
  ],
  providers: [//your providers]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When you navigate to `ComponentA` it will then inject `ComponentB` onto the selector `<component-b></component-b>`

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Actually I am beiginner in ionic. please suggest both parent and child class

Comment: What do you mean by parent and child class? The solution I showed if for 1 entire page/component

Comment: What is AppProvider here ?

Comment: That's the provider, i.e service for the component. You would need to import that if your component is calling a service to do http calls.

Comment: I need component A to be used in component B.
where in html of component B I have to used selector tag of A
i.e. 
<componentA></componentA>

Comment: I updated my answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks alot, yes this is what i was looking for

Comment: @PratikSinha please mark this as correct for the next user experiencing this